# Why does printing 5000 numbers in F# Interactive cause a StackOverflowException?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Tested on F# 3.1 on windows 7

> fsi.PrintLength <- 5000;;
>
> [1..5000];;
>
> Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
> Session termination detected. Press Enter to restart.

on Mono (F# 4.0), there doesn't seem to be such a limitation.

Comment: Sounds like the F# Interactive would benefit from https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5663074-enable-a-compiler-warning-when-a-recursive-algorit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the [formatting module](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/20a9d20e7a3752244b03f62147e453db748a08eb/src/utils/sformat.fs) that takes care of pretty printing to F# Interactive.

There are some non-tail recursive functions that uses `PrintLength` e.g. `boundedUnfoldL` in this [line](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/20a9d20e7a3752244b03f62147e453db748a08eb/src/utils/sformat.fs#L952). Implementation of [`boundedUnfoldL`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/20a9d20e7a3752244b03f62147e453db748a08eb/src/utils/sformat.fs#L196-L208) is indeed not tail-recursive:

```
let boundedUnfoldL
                (itemL     : 'a -> layout)
                (project   : 'z -> ('a * 'z) option)
                (stopShort : 'z -> bool)
                (z : 'z)
                maxLength =
      let rec consume n z =
        if stopShort z then [wordL "..."] else
        match project z with
          | None       -> []  // exhaused input 
          | Some (x,z) -> if n<=0 then [wordL "..."]               // hit print_length limit 
                                  else itemL x :: consume (n-1) z  // cons recursive... 
      consume maxLength z
```

I don't know why it doesn't blow up on Mono. It would be surprising if F# Interactive on Mono can handle length > 5000 successfully.

You can report this as a bug to https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic.

Comment: Maybe they fixed it in F# 4.0 ?